# How do I create a folder shortcut that works for all other people?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, onedrive-for-business

## Question

I have the following folder structure on a teamsite:

```
Vegetables
  |
  |--- Carrot
  |--- Tomato
Fruits
  |
  |--- Banana
```

My final goal is to have folder `Tomato` under `Fruits` and to communicate to `Vegetables` visitors that the `Tomato` folder is moved.

I moved `Tomato` under `Fruits`, and to prevent that people who visit the `Vegetables` folder are confused, I created a [link to `Fruits/Tomato`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-link-in-a-document-library-346b1eb9-1e71-4155-80ca-f868d058a56a) in `Vegetables`.

## Problem

However, people who sync both `Vegetables` and `Fruits` folders with OneDrive for Business now see an `.aspx` file in `Vegetables`. When they click on it, various things can happen (based on what program is associated with `.aspx`), but they're not transported to `Fruits/Tomato`.

## What I tried

### Regular shortcut

I tried creating a `.lnk` file (a regular shortcut in Windows Explorer).
This doesn't work as `.lnk` files point to an absolute path.

If my OneDrive for Business syncs the `Vegetables` and `Fruits` folder they end up in:

```
c:\Users\my_user\org\teamsite\vegetables
c:\Users\my_user\org\teamsite\fruits
```

A `.lnk` file in the `Vegetables` folder would point to `c:\Users\my_user\org\teamsite\fruits\tomato` and when it's synced to `another_user` the `.lnk` file points to a non-existent location.

### Relative shortcut

[This tool](https://www.csparks.com/Relative/) creates relative '.lnk' files.
So now it points to `..\fruits\tomato`.
This relative shortcut unfortunately does not work for other users for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create the shortcut using the %USERPROFILE% environment variable? This then replaces C:\Users\my_user so your path the shortcut would point to would be:

%USERPROFILE%\org\teamsite\fruits\tomato

This should work as it is not user specific and is just using a environment variable that should already be set.

Comment: Kinda works, but now I find that not all users sync the full teamsite. If e.g. there's a parent folder `groceries` containing `vegetables` and `fruits`, some might sync that directly, some might sync the full teamsite. I.e. their folder path might look like `c:\Users\my_user\org\teamsite\vegetables` or  `c:\Users\my_user\org\teamsite\groceries\vegetables`